# Spacing appears in Vim Airline on right side

Tags: plugin-airline

I just successfully installed [vim-airline](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline), and all the required stuff. I've downloaded the powerline-fonts, and successfully installed them. The only problem right now I'm having is: On right side of the bar from my angle, it shows some spacing between arrows and boxes like in the following picture:

[image: Spacing between arrow and box on right side]

I've applied a lot of techniques to make it look properly, but nothing makes it work.

Note: No matter, how wide or short the screen is - the spacing remains consistent.

Comment: have you tried changing the font-size ? also you can try with this font that works great : https://github.com/larsenwork/monoid

Comment: Yes, I've. Changing the font-size makes the space out, but at the same time, it also makes the arrow (much more)bigger than the box, and it looks awkward.

Comment: You should see https://github.com/bling/vim-airline/issues/702

Comment: Installing Monoid didn't help.

Comment: No, neither one helped.

Comment: I think this is a terminal related problem, more than a Vim specific issue

Comment: I'm using iTerm, and regarding settings, I've done the settings. And please note that I've install `input` font from powerline-fonts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27133/discussion-between-nobe4-and-arslan-ali).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try adding the following line in your vimrc :

```
let g:airline#extensions#whitespace#mixed_indent_algo = 1
```

Also, some fonts may work better than others. e.g. :

- http://larsenwork.com/monoid/
- https://github.com/powerline/fonts/tree/master/Inconsolata

Comment: I'm not sure why this is the accepted answer. The first suggestion doesn't change the padding on the right-hand side at all and most of us chose the font we did because we like it better than all of the other fonts. I'll fork vim-airline and see if I can find the source.